# PDF content Overlapped in header and footer

Tags: c#, pdf, header, itext, footer

created pdf using itextsharp. Included header and footer using PdfPageEventHelper. but the content is overlapped in 2nd page onwards. How to set the content area for the table of contents.

Comment: Increase the margins. I'm just guessing, you don't show us any code.

Comment: See [Why does my header overlap with my content?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-does-my-header-overlap-my-content) Also: if you don't show any code, you shouldn't expect an answer.

Comment: @sibysunny *when the number of pages increases it overlaped. on first page its worked fine.* - this is not the commonly observed behavior. Thus, there is some bug in your use of iText. If you show (the pivotal parts) of your code and parameter values used, we may be able to help.

Comment: @PauloSoares Thanks it works